# Getting Inner Value of "name" / "value" of button in Razor Pages Asp.net 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages, model-binding

working on something and stuck at this:

My Razor Page looks like this:

```
 <tbody>
         @foreach(var item in Model.Terminy)
        {
            <tr>
            <form method="post"> <td> <center><button asp-page-handler="edit" class="btn btn-success" value="@item.Dzień_Tygodnia">@item.Dzień_Tygodnia</button><br /></center></td></form>
           <form method="post"><td> <center><button asp-page-handler="edit" class="btn btn-success" name="@item.Dzień_Tygodnia" value="@item.Godzina">@item.Godzina</button></center></td></form>
           <form method="post"> <td> <center><button asp-page-handler="edit" class="btn btn-success" name="@item.Dzień_Tygodnia" value="@item.Godzina1">@item.Godzina1</button></center></td></form>
           <form method="post"> <td> <center><button asp-page-handler="edit" class="btn btn-success" name="@item.Dzień_Tygodnia" value="@item.Godzina2">@item.Godzina2</button></center></td></form>
           <form method="post"> <td> <center><button asp-page-handler="edit" class="btn btn-success" name="@item.Dzień_Tygodnia" value="@item.Godzina3">@item.Godzina3</button></center></td></form>
           <form method="post"> <td> <center><button asp-page-handler="edit" class="btn btn-success" name="@item.Dzień_Tygodnia" value="@item.Godzina4">@item.Godzina4</button></center></td></form>
            <form method="post"> <td> <center><button asp-page-handler="edit" class="btn btn-success" name="@item.Dzień_Tygodnia" value="@item.Godzina5">@item.Godzina5</button></center></td></form>
             <form method="post"><td> <center><button asp-page-handler="edit" class="btn btn-success" name="@item.Dzień_Tygodnia" value="@item.Godzina6">@item.Godzina6</button></center></td></form>
            <form method="post"> <td> <center><button asp-page-handler="edit" class="btn btn-success" name="@item.Dzień_Tygodnia" value="@item.Godzina7">@item.Godzina7</button></center></td></form>
             <form method="post"><td> <center><button asp-page-handler="edit" class="btn btn-success" name="@item.Dzień_Tygodnia" value="@item.Godzina8">@item.Godzina8</button></center></td></form>
             <form method="post"><td> <center><button asp-page-handler="edit" class="btn btn-success" name="@item.Dzień_Tygodnia" value="@item.Godzina9">@item.Godzina9</button></center></td></form>
            </tr>
        }
        
    </tbody>
```

This is single element:

```
<form method="post"><td> <center><button asp-page-handler="edit" class="btn btn-success" name="@item.Dzień_Tygodnia" value="@item.Godzina">@item.Godzina</button></center></td></form>
```

Now the thing is:
In Model class on my OnPostAsync method i need to get inner value of "value" and "name" after click on button.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        
{

}
```

Stuck at this since 5P.M and now is 7P.M and found nothing. Hope you guys can help me find this out. Will be greatful.

Comment: There are a lot of things wrong with this. First, I would not wrap TD elements in a form, that is invalid HTML. Next, using a loop to create your button elements is fine, but I would not create that many forms.

Comment: @MatthewM. Razor page looks like this: https://imgur.com/a/ElGRMro It must be this way. Every single number is a single button that will allow someone to click this number and schedule an event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may misunderstand form submit. It can only post the value of `input`/`select`/`textarea` element. And it cannot post the `name` attribute's  value to the backend. `name` attribute is used for model binding, bind the property with the same name of the `name` attribute value.

**One way** is to add hidden two inputs to every form:

```
@page
@model IndexModel

<table>
    <tbody>
         @foreach(var item in Model.Terminy)
        {
            <tr>
            <form method="post"> 
                <td> 
                    <center>
                        <input name="Dzień_Tygodnia" value="@item.Dzień_Tygodnia" hidden/>
                        <button asp-page-handler="edit" class="btn btn-success" value="@item.Dzień_Tygodnia">@item.Dzień_Tygodnia</button><br />
                    </center>
                </td>
           </form>
           <form method="post">
               <td> 
                   <center>
                       <input name="Dzień_Tygodnia" value="@item.Dzień_Tygodnia" hidden/>
                       <input name="Godzina" value="@item.Godzina" hidden/>
                       <button asp-page-handler="edit" class="btn btn-success" name="@item.Dzień_Tygodnia" value="@item.Godzina">@item.Godzina</button>
                   </center>
               </td>
            </form>
           <form method="post"> 
               <td> 
                   <center>
                       <input name="Dzień_Tygodnia" value="@item.Dzień_Tygodnia" hidden/>
                       <input name="Godzina1" value="@item.Godzina1" hidden/>
                       <button asp-page-handler="edit" class="btn btn-success" name="@item.Dzień_Tygodnia" value="@item.Godzina1">@item.Godzina1</button>
           </center></td></form>
           <form method="post"> <td> <center>
               <input name="Dzień_Tygodnia" value="@item.Dzień_Tygodnia" hidden/>
               <input name="Godzina2" value="@item.Godzina2" hidden/>
               <button asp-page-handler="edit" class="btn btn-success" name="@item.Dzień_Tygodnia" value="@item.Godzina2">@item.Godzina2</button></center></td></form>
           <form method="post"> <td> <center>
               <input name="Dzień_Tygodnia" value="@item.Dzień_Tygodnia" hidden/>
                <input name="Godzina3" value="@item.Godzina3" hidden/>
               <button asp-page-handler="edit" class="btn btn-success" name="@item.Dzień_Tygodnia" value="@item.Godzina3">@item.Godzina3</button></center></td></form>
            </tr>
       //more forms..........
        }
        
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Backend:

```
public IActionResult OnPostEdit(Terminy model)
{
    //do your stuff.........
    
}
```

Model:

```
public class Terminy
{
    public string Dzień_Tygodnia { get; set; }
    public string Godzina { get; set; }
    public string Godzina1 { get; set; }
    public string Godzina2 { get; set; }
    public string Godzina3 { get; set; }
    //other properties...........
}
```

---

**Another way** is that you can use [asp-route-{value} tag helper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-6.0#asp-page):

```
@page
@model IndexModel

<table>
    <tbody>
        @foreach(var item in Model.Terminy)
        {
            <tr>
            <form method="post"> <td> <center><button class="btn btn-success" asp-route-name="" asp-route-value="@item.Dzień_Tygodnia">@item.Dzień_Tygodnia</button><br /></center></td></form>
           <form method="post"><td> <center><button class="btn btn-success" asp-route-name="@item.Dzień_Tygodnia" asp-route-value="@item.Godzina">@item.Godzina</button></center></td></form>
           <form method="post"> <td> <center><button class="btn btn-success" asp-route-name="@item.Dzień_Tygodnia" asp-route-value="@item.Godzina1">@item.Godzina1</button></center></td></form>
           <form method="post"> <td> <center><button class="btn btn-success" asp-route-name="@item.Dzień_Tygodnia" asp-route-value="@item.Godzina2">@item.Godzina2</button></center></td></form>
           <form method="post"> <td> <center><button class="btn btn-success" asp-route-name="@item.Dzień_Tygodnia" asp-route-value="@item.Godzina3">@item.Godzina3</button></center></td></form>
           @*//other forms...........             *@
            </tr>
        }
        
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Backend:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string name,string value)
{
    //do your stuff.........
}
```

Comment: This works for me, thanks for your help :) I will use second option because this is what i wanted. I have been trying with that but something went wrong, now it works and my click pass values :) Thanks!!!

Comment: i will do it now.

Comment: after implementing this new idea comes to my mind. I need to change this value after clicking to "Unavaliable". Do you have any ideas how i can put this?

Comment: Hi, did you want to change the pass `name` and `value` data when click the `Unavaliable` button? If though I suggest you using js to achieve your requirement. Because `asp-route-xxx` tag helper will generate the href html code when page load, you cannot change the `asp-route-xxx` value but you can change the href for the query string `?name=xxx&value==xxx`.

Comment: Yes i am thinking about it. Now i am implementing changing value of button. My button is rendered automatically after call to database. If i change value from in example 5 to break in database, website automatically will render new view. After this i have to make some logic for "danger" button like (if value == "break") { danger button } else "success" button @rena

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72378087/changing-value-in-database-for-specific-cell