# Changing value in database for specific cell

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor-pages, model-binding

working on something and stuck at this:

My Razor Page looks like this:

```
<tbody>
     @foreach(var item in Model.Terminy)
    {
            <tr>
       <form method="post"> <td> <center><button class="btn btn-success"  asp-route-day="" asp-route-value="@item.Dzień_Tygodnia">@item.Dzień_Tygodnia</button><br /></center></td></form>
       <form method="post"> <td> <center><button class="btn btn-success" asp-route-column="@nameof(@item.Godzina)" asp-route-id="@item.Id" asp-route-day="@item.Dzień_Tygodnia" asp-route-value="@item.Godzina">@item.Godzina</button></center></td></form>
       <form method="post"> <td> <center><button class="btn btn-success" asp-route-column="@nameof(@item.Godzina1)" asp-route-id="@item.Id"  asp-route-day="@item.Dzień_Tygodnia" asp-route-value="@item.Godzina1">@item.Godzina1</button></center></td></form>
       <form method="post"> <td> <center><button class="btn btn-success" asp-route-column="@nameof(@item.Godzina2)" asp-route-id="@item.Id"  asp-route-day="@item.Dzień_Tygodnia" asp-route-value="@item.Godzina2">@item.Godzina2</button></center></td></form>
       <form method="post"> <td> <center><button class="btn btn-success" asp-route-column="@nameof(@item.Godzina3)" asp-route-id="@item.Id"  asp-route-day="@item.Dzień_Tygodnia" asp-route-value="@item.Godzina3">@item.Godzina3</button></center></td></form>
       <form method="post"> <td> <center><button class="btn btn-success" asp-route-column="@nameof(@item.Godzina4)" asp-route-id="@item.Id"   asp-route-day="@item.Dzień_Tygodnia" asp-route-value="@item.Godzina4">@item.Godzina4</button></center></td></form>
       <form method="post"> <td> <center><button class="btn btn-success" asp-route-column="@nameof(@item.Godzina5)" asp-route-id="@item.Id"  asp-route-day="@item.Dzień_Tygodnia" asp-route-value="@item.Godzina5">@item.Godzina5</button></center></td></form>
       <form method="post"> <td> <center><button class="btn btn-success" asp-route-column="@nameof(@item.Godzina6)" asp-route-id="@item.Id"  asp-route-day="@item.Dzień_Tygodnia" asp-route-value="@item.Godzina6">@item.Godzina6</button></center></td></form>
       <form method="post"> <td> <center><button class="btn btn-success" asp-route-column="@nameof(@item.Godzina7)" asp-route-id="@item.Id"  asp-route-day="@item.Dzień_Tygodnia" asp-route-value="@item.Godzina7">@item.Godzina7</button></center></td></form>
       <form method="post"> <td> <center><button class="btn btn-success" asp-route-column="@nameof(@item.Godzina8)" asp-route-id="@item.Id"  asp-route-day="@item.Dzień_Tygodnia" asp-route-value="@item.Godzina8">@item.Godzina8</button></center></td></form>
       <form method="post"> <td> <center><button class="btn btn-success" asp-route-column="@nameof(@item.Godzina9)" asp-route-id="@item.Id"  asp-route-day="@item.Dzień_Tygodnia" asp-route-value="@item.Godzina9">@item.Godzina9</button></center></td></form>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

It looks like this:
[image: Table like this]

After clicking one of button my backend do some staff and looks like this:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(int id, string column, string day, string value)
        {
            return RedirectToPage("Potwierdzenie");
        }
```

Now i want to change value of clicked button from in example 5 to None in database. Any ideas how i can do this?
I have got class where i can schedule these values:

```
      public IActionResult OnPostEdit()
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    Terminy.Id = Id;
                    repo.UpdateAsync(Terminy);
                    repo.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                return RedirectToPage("ADMIN_ListaTerminów");
            }
```

and now i need to create this one: from value to none.

After switching value in database for specific cell i am going to implement color change of button

Comment: Wondering if i can take id of button and change its value and change it? Whole table is built automatically and its little complex. Any ideas?

Comment: `thinking on how to get name of @item. Godzina which is "Godzina" which is column name so then I will easily get my goal..
`
did you try to use the `nameof()` in C#?

And I suggest creating a stored procedure in database and call it with an ID and name that you want to change!

Comment: @HusseinBeygi its too far.. I dont want stored procedures. Just need to pass "@item.Godzina" value and then i will use sql call to database.

Comment: You can take the name using `nameof(@(item.Godzina))` and I think you need to split the name a little!

Comment: @HusseinBeygi It works. Thanks. Now i need to figure out next steps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so i am done with it.

My solution is:
After clicking button my backend update value in database, so my view will automatically render button with "None" value.

After this my implementation will check if value is equal "None" and if yes mark this button as

```
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">None</button>
```

[image: After upgrade]

thanks all for comments. i really appreciate this